# text layout in custom rendered UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsstring

I am trying to custom render text within a UITableViewCell.  This text can be over a number of lines and can contain http links, font and colour changes.  I have looked at the sizeWithFont methods of NSString, but can't really work out a good way of rendering each part of the string so that it all runs together correctly.

Do I need to render each word separately to get it to fit properly, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

can you just generate appropriate HTML and render the whole thing with a UIWebView?

Comment: I could do this, but I cannot work out how to dynamically size the UIWebView.  Any pointers would be great

Comment: Also, UIWebView got too slow to have one per cell in a UITableView.  Ended up going with a custom render for each word and calculating the next word position by using the bounding rectangle for the word